# Java Scaning from file, ends method?

Tags: java, methods

The program jumps out of the method when it gets to `list[counter] = fi.nextInt();` why?

Scores.txt contains "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" at the moment, and for some reason it is wiped blank every time the program runs. There is no Exceptions in the console, I am using eclipse.

Code:

```
int[] getValues() throws Exception{
    Scanner fi = new Scanner(new File("./src/oppgave_2_v2/Scores.txt"));
    int[] list = new int[10];

    for(int counter = 0; counter < list.length; counter++){
        list[counter] = fi.nextInt();

    }

    fi.close();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: method `fi.nextInt` throws an exception...

Comment: To clarify the "method" I am taking about is getValues() and it continus on the main code after the jump out, with no errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, I can post the solution if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not getting an `int` from the `nextInt()` method so it's throwing the exception. Print the stack trace to see what's happening. If the `Scanner` is seeing a String token from the file instead, just convert to an int with `Integer.valueOf(fi.next());`. Really, you should be checking if there's an `int` available with: `hasNextInt()` before actually doing `nextInt()`.

Comment: No exception in the console and `list[counter] = Integer.valueOf(fi.next());` did not do any difference. I just discovered that Scores.txt gets wiped every time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Methods of type nextXXX() assume the next characters in the string are of type XXX. It won't give you anything but an exception if you try nextInt() and the first character is a letter p -_-